# Заголовок E-mail

Tags: html, css, php

Что нужно прописать в заголовках E-mail, чтобы почтовая служба обрабатывала HTML теги, как теги, а не текст?

А так же в верстке письма нужно все писать начиная с <html>, <body> или сразу контент письма, т.е. все, что после <body>?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотри 4-ый пример у [функции mail](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php)!

Answer (score 0):

`$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";`
Пример: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php